# How to use a Matlab GUI slider to display image timeframes

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

First of all, I need to be able to select and load multiple image files using the function 'uigetfile'. Then, I need to use a slider to display the successive timeframes of the loaded images onto the axes. So the question is, how to load multiple image files into the GUI and how to use a slider to display through the multiple images one by one. I have a feeling that the function 'dir' needs to be used to select multiple images in 'uigetfile', but I am not sure how to implement it. I am using GUIDE.

This is the image loading push button code.

```
function loadImagePushButton_Callback(hObject,~,handles)

[fileName,pathName] = uigetfile('*.*');
normalImage = imread(fullfile(pathName,fileName));
handles.normalimage = normalImage;
axes(handles.imageDisplay)
imshow(normalImage)
guidata(hObject,handles)

end
```

This is the slider for displaying images one by one.

```
function imageFrameSlider_Callback(hObject,~,handles)

normalImage = handles.normalimage;
sliderValue = get(hObject,'Value');
nextImage = %?%?%?% Not sure what to code here
axes(handles.imageDisplay)
imshow(nextImage)

end
```

Comment: you can select multiple files with `uigetfile` by adding the option `'MultiSelect','on'`. -> `[fileName,pathName] = uigetfile('*.*','MultiSelect','on');` I don't know about the rest though.

Comment: @ Brocodile - It still doesn't seem to work, I can only choose single files even when using that option.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul How are you trying to select multiple files? Are you holding down the shift key?

Comment: @ Brocodile & Suever - Never mind I just had a typo, it works. But I am getting an error after opening the multiple files. The code after that line doesn't seem to know what to do with multiple files as opposed to a single one.

Comment: Because `fileName` is now a `cell array` sized `[1x<NumberOfFiles>]`. You will need to adress it accordingly.

Comment: @ Brocodile - I changed the line, although this only loads the first image onto the axes. `normalImage = imread(fullfile(pathName,fileName{1}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to store the images in the `handles` variable and then you can access them from within your slider callback.

```
function loadImagePushButton_Callback(hObject,~,handles)
    % Load your images
    [fileName, pathName] = uigetfile('*.*', 'MultiSelect', 'on');

    % Cancel if user hit cancel
    if isequal(fileName, 0); return; end

    % Make sure that fileName is a cell
    if ischar(fileName); fileName = {fileName}; end

    % Load all images into a cell array and store it in the handles structure
    filenames = fullfile(pathName, fileName);
    handles.imagedata = cellfun(@imread, filenames, 'uniformoutput', 0);

    % Display the first one and store the graphics handle to the imshow object
    handles.image = imshow(handles.imagedata{1}, 'Parent', handles.imageDisplay);

    % Update the slider to accomodate all of the images
    set(handles.hslider, 'Min', 1, 'Max', numel(filenames), ...
                         'SliderStep', [1 1]/(numel(filenames) - 1), 'Value', 1)

    % Now save guidata
    guidata(hObject, handles);
end

function imageFrameSlider_Callback(hObject,~,handles)
    % Figure out which image to show
    index = get(hObject, 'Value');

    % Update existing image object in the GUI using this image data
    set(handles.image, 'CData', handles.imagedata{index});  
end
```

Comment: @ Suever - It seems that `images{1}` and `handles.imageDisplay` are undefined variables in `handles.image = imshow(images{1},'Parent',handles.imageDisplay);`. How could I correct this?

Comment: @Senyokbalgul I fixed the issue with `images{1}` but based on your code, `handles.imageDisplay` should be an axes object that you define in your GUI.

Comment: @ Suever - It seems that when I load the images, the slider bar is automatically set at the end of the slider. So, I can only go backwards (pulling to the left) , which results in an error that `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals`.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul You need to set the range of your slider. I will update. Updated.

Comment: @ Suever - It seems that `StepSize` is not an existing parameter and it seems that it is `SliderStep` instead: `set(handles.hslider, 'Min', 1, 'Max', numel(fileName), 'SliderStep', [1 1], 'Value', 1)`. It seems to be working now but I can slide through only two images for some reason.

Comment: @ Suever - I have uploaded six images.

Comment: Check the size of `fileNames` within your code to be sure.

Comment: `disp(num2str(size(fileName)))` and `disp(num2str(size(filenames)))` both return {1,6}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117426/discussion-between-suever-and-senyokbalgul).